# javapath is not showing

Tags: bashrc

I installed Java, but I don't get the Java path when I am typing `echo $JAVA_HOME`, and also I am getting the following error message when I open a terminal
bash:

```
/home/ramesh/.bashrc: line 128: syntax error: unexpected end of file
ramesh@ramesh-H61M-S2P-B3:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `$JAVA_HOME` is set by default.
Normally it is set within the file `/etc/environment` for every user.
Otherwise you can set it in `$HOME/.bashrc` for yourself:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/sdk/basis/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug the error on line 128 of your .bashrc file, we would need to see the file.

In terms of JAVA_HOME environment variable, this is normally not set for the user.  Which Java are you using?  If you are using openjdk-7 from ubuntu then you can use this for JAVA_HOME

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```